# Use of progressive in this situation incorrect?

Tags: grammar, tense

> The only thing you can do is eating it.
>
> The only thing you can do is eat it.
>
> The only thing you can do is jumping on it.
>
> The only thing you can do is jump on it.

I am wondering if using the progressive here is wrong, because it does sound wrong, but I am not 100% sure why it's wrong.

Comment: You shouldn't have ***any*** "tensed" form of the verb. It's supposed to be an ***infinitive*** - usually, "unmarked" (without the "infinitive marker" ***to*** before the verb), but at least *some* people will say/write [*All you can do is **to** wait*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22all+you+can+do+is+to+wait%22) But as a learner all you need ***to*** know (with infinitive marker almost *always* included there! :) is that other people *might* include ***to*** (but you probably shouldn't).

Answer (score 3):

The only thing you can do is [to] eat it. to is optional.

No progressive, just the bare form of the verb.

Basically, after **is** you get the bare verb or to plus a bare verb.

Compare:
Eating it is the only thing you can do. There *eating* is not a progressive, it is a gerund noun.

Although the to is left out, it is the clue to the grammatical form here of a purpose clause.

Comment: Good point about the *optional* infinitive marker. But usually *not* included, I think.

Comment: But what I *don't* understand is why [***Reading** was the only thing I could do*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22reading+was+the+only+thing+i+could%22) is fine (and has occurred in print a few times), whereas *The only thing I could do was **reading*** sounds awful to me, and doesn't occur at all in Google Books. Conversely, there are many written instances of *The only thing I could do was **to read*** (and plenty more without ***to***), but none at all of ***To read** was the only thing I could do*. I feel there must be some "principle" involved there, but it's beyond me.

Comment: so "is eating it" is wrong?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Please stop it, would you? I gave an example with a noun gerund in the position of a subject in a sentence.

Comment: @notsharingjake The parse of the sentence is not: "is eating". The dog is eating his dinner. **There it is a progressive tense**. The parse of your sentence is this: All you can do//is//eat. All you can //is//wait. The flag on the wall//is//large. The predicate here is the verb eat.

Comment: Please stop ***what**?* You have some real problems, man!

Comment: @FumbleFingers You are, basically, not adding anything to what I said. Also, you keep giving answers in comments under the question instead of answering. When I do that, my stuff gets moved, when you do it, the mods let it stay. After "is" you need a noun